# qtranslate wordpress разные классы странице

Tags: css, wordpress, html5

Здравствуйте товарищи! Делаю сайт на 2 языках, русский и иврит, можно как то с помощью этого плагина редактировать css стили на одной странице но чтобы отображались они на разных языках по разному, тот же direction:rtl нужно сделать на странице с иврит переводом, а direction:ltr на русской. Что подскажите?

Answer (score 1):

```
<? if (qtrans_getLanguage() == 'ru') { ?>
    <style>
        body {direction:ltr;}
    </style>
<? } else { ?>
    <style>
        body {direction:rtl;}
    </style>
<? } ?>
```

Либо, если вы используете всё таки [qTranslate X](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/): `qtranxf_getLanguage()`